# How to include Ionic 4 Component into Groovy Server Page (GSP)?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, grails

I would like to change some parts of my groovy server page into the ionic component. How can I achieve this?

In the past, I've tried to build the ionic project with **ionic build** and import the compiled javascript into GSP with the  tag while it still not works. Such a method is able to work on importing Angular components into GSP but not for Ionic.

```html
<app-root></app-root>
<g:javascript src="common.js" />
<g:javascript src="es2015-polyfills.js" />
<g:javascript src="home-home-module.js" />
<g:javascript src="main.js" />
<g:javascript src="polyfills.js" />
<g:javascript src="runtime.js" />
<g:javascript src="styles.js" />
<g:javascript src="vendor.js" />
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

I expect to get the hello world string on the page that I called my app-root selector but I get nothing.